# DataTables: Uncaught TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the function below

```
footerCallback: function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
    var api = this.api();
    // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
    var intVal = function ( i ) {

        return typeof i === 'string' ?
            i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
            typeof i === 'number' ?
                i : 0;

    };
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i <=96; i++) { 
        if (api.column(i).data().length){
            console.log('[+] api.column( i ).data()');
            console.log(api.column( i ).data());
            var total = api.column( i ).data().reduce( function (a, b) {
                console.log( intVal(a) + intVal(b));
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }) 
            }
        else { 
            total = 0
        };
        // Total over this page
        if (api.column(i).data().length){
            var pageTotal = api.column( i, { page: 'current'} ).data().reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            })
        }
        else{ 
            pageTotal = 0
        };

        // Update footer
        $( api.column(i).footer() ).html(total);
    }

    // Total over all pages

},
```

It sums the values in a column and adds it to the total. So I have two versions. One that works, one that does not. Exactly the same code used in both pages

**Working Console.Log**

[image]

**Broken Console.Log**

Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value`

[image]

I have noticed that the broken one has red text and has double quotes around each 0 or 1.

The strange thing is.... the broken version does the job in as much as the numbers appear for the totals, but because of the error, the page is still broken

Answer (score 1):

Removing the following worked - it was being unused but still causing an issue

```
 // Total over this page
        if (api.column(i).data().length){
            var pageTotal = api.column( i, { page: 'current'} ).data().reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            })
        }
        else{ 
            pageTotal = 0
        };
```